Concatenating buffers from Azure Speech Service tts
I have a huge text, coming from an academic paper, that I want to transform into audio. Because the audio is too big, I split it into 4096 characters chunks. Then I send it to the OpenAi tts api chunk by chunk, and at the end, I concatenate all the buffers received as responses.
Everything works great, but now I also need the word timestamps, and OpenAi doesn't offer this feature, so now I am testing the Speech Service from azure. I managed to get both the speech and the timestamps using sdk.SpeechSynthesizer. The issue is that my old method that was concatenating the buffers after creating them is not working anymore, probably because of some headers that the buffers might have. I thought about Batch synthetization, but it has no word timestamps, my files are saved on firebase on the deployed env, so I can't create files and then concatenate them with ffmpeg because it would took too long. The only solution that I could find was to stream the output into a file instead of creating the buffers and then concatenating them, but this solution would mess my app flow too much so it's the last resort.
Are there other ways to concatenate the audio buffers that I am not aware?

The simplest answer is that if you want to do buffer concatenation, don't use the Wav format. If azure generates multiple wavs, you will be able to concatenate them, but your media player will be able to play just the first one because each wav has a header that indicates the start of the audio. Azure is able to generate mp3 audio, that are easily concatenable, and that was my solution
